# Storing an image using ajax request inside Postgresql in Spring application

Tags: ajax, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to store an image in postgresql db from my spring application but I am stuck with multiple problems and confusion.

First let me give you the overview of my spring application code:

```
var documentData = new FormData();
    function update(){
        var fname=document.getElementById("fname").value;
        var lname=document.getElementById("lname").value;
        var password=document.getElementById("password").value.trim();
        var email=document.getElementById("email").value;

        documentData.append('fname',fname);
        documentData.append('lname',lname);
        documentData.append('password',password);
        documentData.append('email',email);
        documentData.append('profilePic',$('#profilePic').attr('src'));
        alert($('#profilePic').attr('src'));            
            $
            .ajax({
                type : 'PUT',
                url : baseUrl + "/restApi/UpdateUser",
                data : JSON
                        .stringify({
                             documentData
                        }),
                        success: function(){
                            location.reload(true);          
                           },

                error : function(e) {

                },
                dataType : "json",
                contentType : "application/json"
            });

        }

    }
    $(function () {
    $(":file").change(function () {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

        }
    });

});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $('#profilePic').attr('src', e.target.result);
    $('#viewPic').attr('src',e.target.result);
};
```

**I have this controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/restApi/UpdateUser", method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public ServiceResponse modifyUser(@RequestBody Object user)
    {
        return setDataPut("http://localhost:7020/UpdateUser",user,getUserObject().getUsername(),getUserObject().getPassword());
    }
```

In my **setDataPut** method I am sending response with **GSON**

```
WebResource webResource = client
               .resource(path);
            ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").accept("application/json")
               .put(ClientResponse.class, gson.toJson(object));
```

In model class I took **byte[]** type variable and in db I made column with type [bytea](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-binary.html)
Now In above gson service the call is made to rest services hosted.

```
@CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ModifyUser", method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public ServiceResponse modifyUser(@RequestBody User user) {
 /*Code which deals with storing User data*/

}
```

So I have taken all data through **model User** class.
Now earlier it was working perfectly until I wanted to store image also.
Nothing is getting saved no error.

**Confusion:** If I am sending image with some data then should I change content type or add enctype as "multipart/form-data". But If I use multipart then what should be changed in headers. Like @produces @consumes. Major doubt is whether I need to convert the image in binary code before sending?

**Problem:** I am having trouble in storing image in postgresql through ajax request. Please look through my code what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking quite a lot in one question here.  Essentially, you are asking how to upload files from the browser/client to the Spring-based server, how to handle that upload in the Spring-based server in order to save it into a Postgresql database and associate it with my User entity so that I can fetch it again later.

So, let's have a go at answering all of that for you.

Let's start on the client-side.  This code will upload the chosen file to an existing resource:-

> index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      function upload() {
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', jQuery('#file')[0].files[0]);

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/userImage/userId',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            method: 'POST',
            type: 'POST', // For jQuery < 1.9
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <h1>New File</h1>
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
        <button onclick="upload()">Upload</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, turning our attention to the Spring-bsed server side.  To abstract away the implementation of exactly how to store the uploaded file in the database (and how to update it, and how to fetch it, and how to delete it and so on) I would use [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) otherwise you have a lot of code to write that Spring Content already implements for you.

So, add the following dependencies:

> pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>   // 0.0.11 for Spring Boot 1 dependencies
    </dependency>
```

Configure the database schema creation in one of your config classes:

> Config.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaStores // enable JPA-based storage
public class PostgresqlTestConfig {

    ...dataSource and entityManager, etc beans...    

    @Value("/org/springframework/content/jpa/schema-drop-postgresql.sql")
    private Resource dropReopsitoryTables;

    @Value("/org/springframework/content/jpa/schema-postgresql.sql")
    private Resource dataReopsitorySchema;

    @Bean
    DataSourceInitializer datasourceInitializer() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator =
                new ResourceDatabasePopulator();

        databasePopulator.addScript(dropReopsitoryTables);
        databasePopulator.addScript(dataReopsitorySchema);
        databasePopulator.setIgnoreFailedDrops(true);

        DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        initializer.setDataSource(dataSource());
        initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator);

        return initializer;
    }
}
```

Associate content with your User entity:

> User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {

    ...existing fields...

    @ContentId private String contentId;
    private String mimeType;
}
```

Create a UserStore:

> UserImageStore.java

```
public interface UserImageStore extends AssociativeStore<User, String> {
}
```

Update your controller to handle the upload of files, store them in the database and associating that stored image on your entity:

> UserController.java

```
    @Autowired
    private UserImageStore store;

    ...

    @RequestMapping(value="/userImage/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> setContent(@PathVariable("userId") Long id, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) 
            throws IOException {

        User user = // fetch your existing user here
        user.setMimeType(file.getContentType());

        String originalFilename = file.getOriginalFilename();
        InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = ((WritableResource)store.getResource(originalFilename)).getOutputStream();

        IOUtils.copyLarge(is, os);

        IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(os);

        // associate content (this will update the @ContentId field)
        store.associate(user, originalFilename);

        // save updated content-related info
        save(user); 

        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return null;

    @RequestMapping(value="/userImage/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getContent(@PathVariable("userId") Long id) {

        User user = // fetch your existing user here
        Resource r = store.getResource(user.getContentId());
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentLength(r.getContentLength());
        headers.set("Content-Type", user.getMimeType());
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(r, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return null;
}
```

That's about it.  So what's going to happen here is that when your app starts it sees the dependency on `spring-content-jpa` and then it sees your `UserImageStore`.  Assumes that you want to store images (BLOBs) in jpa and injects a JPA implementation of the `UserImageStore` interface meaning that you don't need to write it yourself.  Spring Content hides the implementation but exposes a relatively simply interface (based on Spring Resource actually) that is `@Autowired` into your controller making that implementation simple.

Anyways, let me know if you are using Spring Data or Spring Boot and I can update this answer so that it is more relevant for you.

HTH

Comment: There is a working example here: https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content-gettingstarted/tree/master/spring-content-associativestore/complete.  This uses Spring Data for the entity management but that is optional.  It also uses `spring-content-fs` but the dependency can be changed to `spring-content-jpa` and that will tell Spring Content to inject a JPA implementation for store interfaces, rather than a fils-system implementation.